# php no symbol regex allowing "&" and "+"

Tags: php, regex

I am perplexed (and not good with regexes).

I have (in my php file):

```
if ( !preg_match ("/^[a-zA-Z\s]+$/",$string)) {
            $valid = False;
}
```

which is suppose to only allow letters and spaces, however when there is an '&' or '+' in the string it allows that.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: `else $valid = true`?

Comment: Where is `$string` coming from?

Comment: Note that "\s" isn't just a space, it's any whitespace character.  Unless you're trying to match across multiple lines, you probably want to use ^[a-zA-Z ]+$ instead.

Comment: I think it is because of this strip_tags(trim($_POST['interest_1']));---Again I am new to PHP

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked if the string actually contains '+' or '&' by echo-ing it.

If you test the regex on this site: http://www.phpliveregex.com/
It does not match + or &, so your regex is correct, just take a look at your input.

Answer (score -1):

Giant enormous humungo-shot in the dark here, but I'm going to guess that `$string = $_GET['test'];` and you're accessing things like:

- `http://example.com/regex.php?test=Fail+`
- `http://example.com/regex.php?test=FAIL&`

And so on. In this case, keep in mind that `+` is decoded to a space, which `\s` allows. And `&` delimits the parameter, so won't appear if you `var_dump($string)`.